# Is it legal to sell packaged food products with only American style nutrition facts on the label?

Tags: england-and-wales, food, retail, labelling, nutrition

Abdul’s food and wine in London sells boxes of Mike and Ikes that are clearly packaged for sale in the USA. Sometimes such foreign packaged food products are sold in England with product information stickers stuck over seemingly to conform with local regulations. These Mike and Ikes have no such covering sticker and list ingredients like Yellow #5 and “artificial flavouring” in all capital letters and which are generally not seen on British food labels.

Are they legal to sell in the UK?

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't say "artificial flavoring"?

Comment: @phoog lol there’s a very good chance that that is what it says, good point.

Answer (score 1):

### Sometimes

What must be shown on UK food labels is detailed [here](https://www.gov.uk/food-labelling-and-packaging/print). What must be shown in the USA is [here](https://www.fda.gov/food/food-labeling-nutrition).

In many circumstances, the requirements are comparable, that is, a product labeled to the US requirements will meet the UK requirements. In some they won’t; that’s when you’ll see the covering sticker.

Hence the answer “sometimes”.

Comment: Can you give a citation for the allowance of uncovered American labelling in appropriate circumstances? For example, what are called artificial flavourings in the U.S. may not even be legal to include in food products in the UK, while what may be called natural flavourings in the U.S. may not meet the U.K. definitions. Therefore, just based on examining the label it may very well not be possible to determine that the label suitably reflects the contents for the British market/jurisdiction.